# y + height must be <= bitmap.height() in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to create a bitmap form another but for each try it's a crash, this the error message

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:557)
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:522)
>               saveBitmap(GesturesActivity.java:166)

This is where i try the creation :

```
public void saveBitmap(){
    Bitmap bitmapToSave = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapToSave);
    view.draw(canvas);

    int width = bitmapToSave.getWidth();
    int height = bitmapToSave.getHeight();
    System.out.println("view : "+view.getWidth());
    System.out.println("view : "+view.getHeight());
    System.out.println("btmp Width : "+width);
    System.out.println("btmp Height : "+height);

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapToSave, 0, view.getTop(), view.getWidth(), view.getWidth());
    SaveImage(result);
}
```

Thanks for your help :D

This is my logcat :

```
> System.out﹕ view : 480
System.out﹕ view : 480
System.out﹕ btmp Width : 480
System.out﹕ btmp Height : 480
```

Comment: "but for each try it's a crash." Any error messages?

Comment: O sorry but before update of my code, there were - after "btmp width " and others. My question is edited

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapToSave, 0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
```

I think the issue is view.getTop is a value greater than 0. So `view.GetTop + view.getHeight()` is not less than bitmap.height.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, in the second `BitmapCreate`:

```
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapToSave, 0, view.getTop(), view.getWidth(), view.getWidth());
```

The height argument (the last one) is set to be `View.getWidth()`. However, nowhere in the code have you checked that the width of the view, added to the Top of the view, is not greater than the height of `bitmapToSave`. A check to this effect should go in.