# Splitting bitmap file produces y + height must be <= bitmap.height() error

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I am trying to split bitmap with this method I made:

```
private List<Bitmap> splitBitmap(File file, int everyPixel)
{
    Bitmap comicBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    List<Bitmap> segments = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    if(comicBitmap == null)
        return segments;

    int height = comicBitmap.getHeight();
    int width = comicBitmap.getWidth();
    int h = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i += everyPixel)
    {
        i = i >= height? height : i;

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(comicBitmap, 0, i, width, i + everyPixel);
        segments.add(bitmap);
    }

    return segments;
}
```

The size of the bitmap I am processing is 240x4298. Its a very very long image. I need to generate a list of bitmaps (segmented bitmap from the original source). When the `i` hits 2400, it spews out an error saying:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()`

My logic here is something like:
1.) I start with 0 pixels to 400 pixels in y axis
2.) I start with 400 pixels to 800 pixels in y axis
and so on and so forth...

The current iteration haven't reached 4298 yet and its complaining (at 2400px). Any thought why this so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my new method:

```
private List<Bitmap> splitBitmap(File file, int everyPixel)
{
    Bitmap comicBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    List<Bitmap> segments = new ArrayList<>();

    if(comicBitmap == null)
        return segments;

    int height = comicBitmap.getHeight();
    int width = comicBitmap.getWidth();

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i += everyPixel)
    {
        i = i >= height? height : i;
        int limit = i + everyPixel >= height? height - i : everyPixel;

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(comicBitmap, 0, i, width, limit);
        segments.add(bitmap);
    }

    return segments;
}
```

Notice the lines:

```
i = i >= height? height : i;
int limit = i + everyPixel >= height? height - i : everyPixel;
```

This actually make sure all pixels are accounted for. For example in my case the height is 4298 and I reached 4000. Since I need to process the last 298, the limit should be just 298 instead of my everyPixel value.

The way I see this is that the method `Bitmap.createBitmap(comicBitmap, 0, i, width, limit)` third param (y) actually adds to the 5th param (height). So if I want to process 400-800th pixel it should be:

`Bitmap.createBitmap(comicBitmap, 0, 400, width, 400);`

The third param adds to the 5th when evaluating the final height of the bitmap.

I find this very counter intuitive. But its just me, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As I see from you code, problem is in line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(comicBitmap, 0, i, width, i + everyPixel);
```

For example, you have `width = 1000, height = 3000`, but `everyPixel = 2000`. In second iteration of cycle you will have `i = 2000` and you will try to create bitmap from comicbitmap by getting part with left = 0, top = 2000, width = 1000 and height = i + everyPixel = 4000, but height of overall bitmap is 3000 so you get this error.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959068/y-height-must-be-bitmap-height-in-android) for more info.

Comment: I checked this on the debugger and this was not the case. The reason I place the `i = i >= height? height : i;` for that matter. I am iterating every 400 pixels by the way. As I have said, on the debugger I've detected it complains when my `i` is at 2400. The height I am running against is 4298. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: alright the 4th param should be `everyPixel` only not `i + everyPixel`